# Atlassian Bamboo with Django & Python - Possible?

Tags: python, django, deployment, continuous-integration, bamboo

At my company, we currently use [Atlassian Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/) for our continuous integration tool.  We currently use Java for all of our projects, so it works great.

However, we are considering using a Django + Python for one of our new applications.  I was wondering if it is possible to use Bamboo for this.

First off, let me say that I have a low level of familiarity with Bamboo, as I've only ever used it, not configured it (other than simple changes like changing the svn checkout directory for a build).

Obviously there isn't a lot of point in just running a build (since Python projects don't really build), but I'd like to be able to use Bamboo for running the test suite, as well as use bamboo to deploy the latest code to our various test environments the way we do with our Java projects.

Does Bamboo support this type of thing with a Python project?

Comment: Old question. But I have added py.test as a Bamboo executable and simply use this to run the tests (with junit-xml output specified). Then the JUnit test parser needs to be run as a separate job.

Comment: @SamuelO'Malley can you post an example of how you got that to work?

Comment: @MikeyE - I have actually changed how it is done since this comment was posted. Now I was a Bamboo Script Task and have the contents as `py.test --junit-xml results.xml` and after that I have `if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo "Test Failed"; fi` to swallow the return code. Otherwise Bamboo won't allow you to quarantine an individual test result and will mark the whole Job as failed.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Bamboo essentially just runs a shell script, so this could just as easily be:

```
./manage.py test
```

as it typically is:

```
mvn clean install
```

or:

```
ant compile
```

You may have to massage to output of the Django test runner into traditional JUnit XML output, so that Bamboo can give you pretty graphs on how many tests passed.  Look at [this post](http://redsolo.blogspot.com/2007/11/hudson-embraces-python.html) about using xmlrunner.py to get Python working with [Hudson](http://hudson.dev.java.net/).  Also take a look at [NoseXUnit](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMEXT/NoseXUnit+-+JUnit+like+XML+reporting+for+Python+PyUnit).

Answer (score 16):

You can even add a bootstrap for pip and virtualenv on a clean environment quite easily, which is cool:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py --root=${bamboo.build.working.directory}/tmp --ignore-installed
export PATH=${bamboo.build.working.directory}/tmp/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=${bamboo.build.working.directory}/tmp/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH
pip install --root=${bamboo.build.working.directory}/tmp --ignore-installed virtualenv
virtualenv virtual_tmp
cd virtual_tmp
. bin/activate
echo Pip is located `which pip`
pip install django
pip install djangorestframework
```

Warning, `source bin/activate` does not work as the inline script tasks are stored into an sh file (so `bash` run it in `sh` compatibility mode).

## Edit

Even better, we can run unit tests on the top of it, with xml outputs that can be parsed by the JUnit of bamboo:

```
pip install unittest-xml-reporting
python manage.py test --noinput --testrunner="xmlrunner.extra.djangotestrunner.XMLTestRunner"
```

Comment: @Raffi, can you elaborate a bit more on why source bin/activate does not work in file scripts? Been using it fine in inline scripts, but would like to move as much as possible to file scripts since it makes easier to maintain (version control, etc).

Comment: In the build log of Bamboo and for inline scripts, I have something like `Beginning to execute external process for build 'XXX Django artifactsZZZ #35'\n ... running command line: \n/bin/sh /tmp/SW-DCD-JOB1-35-ScriptBuildTask-9100354988645888838.sh`. The inline script is flushed into a `.sh` file and `/bin/sh` is executed. `sh` does not have `source` builtin command (`type source` returns an error). So `.` is more compatible with what I want here

Answer (score 9):

It turns out it is possible. There are two major integration tasks: test runner results and code coverage results. I assume normal Python 3 codebase  and standard `unittest` test suite.

## Test runner

Bamboo expects test runner results in [JUnit XML format](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/junit-parsing-in-bamboo-289277357.html). There is [separate test runner](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest-xml-reporting/) on the Cheese Shop able to produce such output, but it would require you to write a little code to run it, which is not nice. Better way which keeps the codebase intact is to use [pytest](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest)'s features.

## Code coverage

Bamboo only supports the XML format of Atlassian Clover. Important note here is that you don't need Atlassian Clover plugin enabled (and license for it which costs some bucks). Bamboo works on its own.

Python de facto standard code coverage tool, [coverage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage), produces somewhat 
Cobertura XML format, but there's a [converter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cobertura-clover-transform). There's a [pytest plugin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-cov) for integration with the coverage tool.

## Solution

Here's the [Tox](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tox) environment where I used pytest to make both Bamboo integrations work.

```
[tox]
envlist   = py34
skipsdist = True

[testenv]
setenv     = LANG=C.UTF-8
basepython = python3.4
deps       = -r{toxinidir}/requirements.txt

[testenv:bamboo]
commands = 
  py.test --junitxml=results.xml \
    --cov=project_name --cov-config=tox.ini --cov-report=xml \
    --cov-report=html project_name/test
    coverage2clover -i coverage.xml -o clover.xml
deps = 
    {[testenv]deps}
    pytest
    pytest-cov
    coverage2clover

# read by pytest
[pytest]
python_files = *.py

# read by coverage
[run]
omit=project_name/test/*,project_name/__main__.py
```

Note that both pytest and pytest-cov use `tox.ini` for the configuration that is not supported on command line. It again saves your from having additional clutter in root of your repo. pytest tries to read `tox.ini` automatically. pytest-cov bypasses to [`.coveragerc`](http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.0.3/config.html), but because it's also an INI file, `tox.ini` fits.

On Bamboo side add a [script task](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/script-289277046.html) that runs `tox -e bamboo`. Then add [JUnit parse task](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/junit-parser-289277056.html) to the job. In its dialogue, under *Specify custom results directories* put `results.xml`.

Coverage configuration is done other way.

1. Open *Miscellaneous* tab of your job
2. Check *Use Clover to collect Code Coverage for this build*
3. Select *Clover is already integrated into this build and a clover.xml file will be produced*
4. Type `clover.xml` into *Clover XML Location*

[image]

At this point in your next build you will see total coverage and two charts: *Coverage history* and *Lines of code history*. It's also nice to have interactive HTML produced by coverage tool, so you can drill down to certain line of code.

The settings made above (at least in Bamboo 5.7) has created *Clover Report (System)* in *Artifact* job's tab. Open it and set `htmlcov` to *Location* field, and `*.*` to *Copy pattern*. Bamboo will now collect the HTML reports. You can see it at *Clover* tab of your plan.

Answer (score 0):

If you use pytest you can simply use `py.test --junitxml=/path/to/results/xml/file.xml`